# Multiple instance of superfish?

Tags: jquery, html, css, superfish

Can I get two instances of superfish running on one HTML page? I am not using a CMS, just straight HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I'd imagine it has something to do with editing the superfish.css file, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, all you have to do is give them separate ID's and initialize them like so:

```
$("#menu-1, #menu-2").superfish();
```

Comment: thank you for the response...will this make both menu's use the same styles though? i am hoping to have a much different style for my secondary nav than my main nav.

Comment: @crowdediceb0x yes, you can utilize the same ID that separates both menus and style them accordingly. Take a look at this demo i made showing two different menus running at the same time with different styles: http://jsfiddle.net/GyX35/